# Concurrency and race condition

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition, python-multithreading

I was expecting a race condition to occur here. But it doesn't. Why?

```
import threading

x = 0

def foo():
    global x
    for i in range(1000):
        print x
        x += 1

def bar():
    global x
    for i in range(1000):
        print x
        x -= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=bar)

    t1.start(); t2.start()
    t1.join(); t2.join()

    print x
```

The final value of x always 0. Not only that it seems that the second thread only starts to run after thread 1 has completed it's execution.

Comment: Python GIL global interpreter lock.

Comment: In simple words , only one thread is active at a time . In Python , multi threading does not mean concurrent execution . Its just quick context changes .

Comment: Re, "it seems that the second thread only starts to run after thread 1 has completed."  I don't know how much of a time slice Python gives to one runnable thread before switching to the next, but it does not take long for a modern computer to count to 1000.